# \MakeUppercase and \bibleref

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, cases, bibleref

consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{bibleref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify{\bibleverse}
\begin{document}

Is : \bibleverse{Is}(1:1-3)

IS : \bibleverse{IS}(1:1-3)

\section{Here a reference within a title: \bibleverse{Is}(1:1-3)} % Don't work



\end{document}
```

As you can see, there is two problems in the header.
1. Is has been transformerd to IS, by \MakeUppercase, and so Isaiah became I Samuel!
2. Uppercase is not applied to the book title.

Any idea?I suppose that is a problem of expansion, but I don't get any solution.

Comment: `\section{Here a reference within a title: \protect\NoCaseChange{\protect\bibleverse{Is}(1:1-3)}}` solves problem 1 if you load `\usepackage[overload]{textcase}`, but it doesn't do problem 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `\bibleverse` were expandable, the entire thing would work as desired out of the box. I'm not sure if it is possible, but maybe it is worth a short investigation whether or not an expandable `\bibleverse` could be implemented in `bibleref` (you seem to be on good terms with the maintainer, so maybe you can ask him ;-)).

To solve this, there were several things we have to make sure of

1. `\bibleverse` must be `\protect`ed or made robust so that it does not break when it is written to the `.aux` file.

   - In the MWE I used `\protect`, but you could `\robustify` the entire thing if you like.
2. The arguments of `\bibleverse` must not be touched by `\MakeUppercase`.

   - In the MWE that is achieved with [`textcase`](https://ctan.org/pkg/textcase)'s `\NoCaseChange`. Note that `\NoCaseChange` also needs a `\protect` so that it is not expanded when the `.aux` file is written.
3. The text produced by `\bibleverse` must be uppercased again.

   - That was the tricky bit. Following the advice in section 2.2 of the `titlecase` manual the MWE redefines `\BRbooktitlestyle` to be aware of whether or not uppercasing is enabled. To this end we define a detectable version of `\MakeTextUppercase` that sets a toggle. We can then check for that toggle in `\BRbooktitlestyle`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{bibleref}

\newtoggle{mtc@uppercase}
\newrobustcmd*{\MakeTextUppercaseDetectable}[1]{%
  \MakeTextUppercase{\NoCaseChange{\toggletrue{mtc@uppercase}}#1}%
}

\let\MakeUppercase\MakeTextUppercaseDetectable

\renewcommand{\BRbooktitlestyle}[1]{%
  \iftoggle{mtc@uppercase}
    {\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}
    {#1}}

\begin{document}

Is : \bibleverse{Is}(1:1-3)

IS : \bibleverse{IS}(1:1-3)

\section{Here a reference within a title: \protect\NoCaseChange{\protect\bibleverse{Is}(1:1-3)}}

Is : \bibleverse{Is}(1:1-3)

IS : \bibleverse{IS}(1:1-3)
\end{document}
```

[image: The header reads "HERE A REFERENCE WITHIN A TITLE: ISAIAH 1:1–3", the corresponding section heading is "Here a reference within a title: Isaiah 1:1–3"]

Comment: That nice. Indeed, the best solution would be to make \bibleverse expandable, As you tell, I know well the maintener of bibleref, but, that is the problem, he is not to the origin of the code, and he is still "lost" in the code. And, more of all, he has no such time.  I will think to that (but I need te reread handbook about expansion problem...). Thank anyway for this answer.

Comment: @Maïeul A command with a trailing optional argument (the reference to the verse) cannot be expandable.

Comment: @egreg that what I though, spontanesly.